# React.js: Stacked MultiBarChart of nvd3.js doesn't order layers correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nvd3.js

I'd like to use MultiBarChart and its `stacked` option, but haven't succeeded so far.

Modules I use:

- `nvd3` of version `1.8.2`
- `react-nvd3` of version `0.5.3`

Here's the relevant code.

```
var props = {
  type: "multiBarChart",
  datum: [{
    key: "num",
    values: [{ x: "A0", y: "5" },{ x: "A1", y: "5" },{ x: "A2", y: "5" },{ x: "A3", y: "5" }]
  },{
    key: "num2",
    values: [{ x: "A0", y: "1" },{ x: "A1", y: "1" },{ x: "A2", y: "1" },{ x: "A3", y: "1" }]
  },{
    key: "num3",
    values: [{ x: "A0", y: "2" },{ x: "A1", y: "2" },{ x: "A2", y: "2" },{ x: "A3", y: "2" }]
  }],
  containerStyle: {
    width: 500,
    height: 300
  }
};

...

return (<div><NVD3Chart {...props}/></div>);
```

It works fine with `Grouped` option:

[image]

but doesn't work with `Stacked` option. The last key `num3` covers all the bars, which should be on the sum of `num1` and `num2`:

[image]

When I hover one of them, `num3` bar totally hides `num1` and `num2`, and shows as if the value is `num3` itself:

[image]

Does anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the cause. Values of Y fields should be numerical in `stacked` mode.

Should not be:

```
{
  key: "num",
  values: [{ x: "A0", y: "5" },{ x: "A1", y: "5" },{ x: "A2", y: "5" },{ x: "A3", y: "5" }]
}
```

But:

```
{
  key: "num",
  values: [{ x: "A0", y: 5 },{ x: "A1", y: 5 },{ x: "A2", y: 5 },{ x: "A3", y: 5 }]
}
```